# How to explode a string but not within quotes in php?

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

I have this string:

```
$sc = '[csvtohtml_create include_rows="1-10" 
debug_mode="no" source_type="guess" path="largecsv" 
source_files="FL_insurance_sample - Kopia.csv2"  csv_delimiter="," ]'
```

**I'm trying to figure out how to separate values separated by a space. This is not an issue in itself, but *if the space is within a quote I don't want it to be separated*.**

---

Take a close look at the `source_files` below. (I want the item in the array to be `"FL_insurance_sample - Kopia.csv2"`)

**With:**

```
$args = explode( '=', $sc );
```

**I get this result:**

```
array (size=11)
  0 => string '[csvtohtml_create' (length=17)
  1 => string 'include_rows="1-10"' (length=19)
  2 => string 'debug_mode="no"' (length=15)
  3 => string 'source_type="guess"' (length=19)
  4 => string 'path="largecsv"' (length=15)
  5 => string 'source_files="FL_insurance_sample' (length=33)
  6 => string '-' (length=1)
  7 => string 'Kopia.csv2"' (length=11)
  8 => string '' (length=0)
  9 => string 'csv_delimiter=","' (length=17)
  10 => string ']' (length=1)
```

**The result I want is:**

```
array (size=11)
  0 => string '[csvtohtml_create' (length=17)
  1 => string 'include_rows="1-10"' (length=19)
  2 => string 'debug_mode="no"' (length=15)
  3 => string 'source_type="guess"' (length=19)
  4 => string 'path="largecsv"' (length=15)
  5 => string 'source_files="FL_insurance_sample - Kopia.csv2"' (length=42)
  7 => string 'csv_delimiter=","' (length=17)
  8 => string ']' (length=1)
```

I've been looking at kind of same questions but I'm not sure the answers are the answers I'm searching for. Please put me in the right direction. Is `preg_split` what I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using explode, one option is to use [preg_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php).

*(Note that in the result that you want, the size of the array should be `array(8)` and you skipped a key nr 6)*

The pattern matches

- `"[^"]+"` Match `"..."` using a negated character class
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` What is currently matched should not be part of the result
- `|` Or
- `\h+` Match 1 or more horizontal whitspace characters

Example

```
$sc = '[csvtohtml_create include_rows="1-10" debug_mode="no" source_type="guess" path="largecsv" source_files="FL_insurance_sample - Kopia.csv2"  csv_delimiter="," ]';

var_dump(preg_split('/"[^"]+"(*SKIP)(*F)|\h+/', $sc));
```

Output

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "[csvtohtml_create"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "include_rows="1-10""
  [2]=>
  string(15) "debug_mode="no""
  [3]=>
  string(19) "source_type="guess""
  [4]=>
  string(15) "path="largecsv""
  [5]=>
  string(47) "source_files="FL_insurance_sample - Kopia.csv2""
  [6]=>
  string(17) "csv_delimiter=",""
  [7]=>
  string(1) "]"
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you please describe var the regex actually does? :-)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld Of course, 1 moment

Comment: Thanks a lot. You're the best programmer in the world :-)