# How do I include equals and quotes when extracting from quotes in a string?

Tags: php, regex, string

**I have this string:**

```
$shortcode = '[csvtohtml_create include_rows="1-10" 
debug_mode="no" source_type="guess" path="largecsv" 
source_files="test?output=csv"  csv_delimiter="," ]'
```

I want to retrieve attributes and their values even their equal-signs or spaces within quotes.

This question is based on this question: [How to explode a string but not within quotes in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66163283/how-to-explode-a-string-but-not-within-quotes-in-php/66163363?noredirect=1#66163363)

**I have this code:**

```
$args = preg_split('/"[^"]+"(*SKIP)(*F)|\h+/', $shortcode);
   
$attrs = [];
foreach( $args as $item )
{
    //Only use those items in array $args with = sign
    if ( strpos( $item , '=' ) !== false )
    {
        $sep = explode( '=', $item );
        $key = $sep[0];
        $value = $sep[1];
        $attrs[$key] = str_replace( '"', '', $value );
    }
}

$args = explode( '=', $sc );
```

**I get this result:** (source_files without output=csv)

```
Array attrs
      "include_rows" => "1-10"
      "debug_mode" => "no"
      "source_type" => "guess"
      "path" => "largecsv"
      "source_files" => "test.csv?output"
      "csv_delimiter" => ","
```

**The result I want is:**

```
Array attrs
      "include_rows" => "1-10"
      "debug_mode" => "no"
      "source_type" => "guess"
      "path" => "largecsv"
      "source_files" => "test.csv?output=csv"
      "csv_delimiter" => ","
```

etc...

I guess I should put in equal-sign (or is it ?=) somewhere in here but regex is not my strength...

```
$args = preg_split('/"[^"]+"(*SKIP)(*F)|\h+/', $shortcode);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track with exploding the equals sign. This implementation does `array_shift` to get the key, then `implodes` the rest of the array together.

```
<?php

$sc = '[csvtohtml_create include_rows="1-10" 
debug_mode="no" source_type="guess" path="largecsv" 
source_files="test?output=csv"  csv_delimiter="," ]';

$args = array_filter(array_map('trim', preg_split('/"[^"]+"(*SKIP)(*F)|\h+/', $sc)));
array_shift($args); // remove [csvtohtml
array_pop($args); // remove ]

$output = [];
foreach ($args as $arg) {
    $explode = explode('=', $arg);
    $key = array_shift($explode);
    $value = str_replace('"', '', implode('=', $explode)); // remove str_replace if you want to keep the extra set of quotes
    $output[$key] = $value;
}

print_r($output);
```

Results in

```
Array
(
    [include_rows] => 1-10
    [debug_mode] => no
    [source_type] => guess
    [path] => largecsv
    [source_files] => test?output=csv
    [csv_delimiter] => ,
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Might be easier to get the matches.  Then you can do whatever.  I turn it into a query string and parse into an array:

```
preg_match_all('/[^\s=]+="[^"]*"/', $shortcode, $result);
parse_str(implode('&', $result[0]), $result);
```

Now `$result` yields:

```
Array
(
    [include_rows] => "1-10"
    [debug_mode] => "no"
    [source_type] => "guess"
    [path] => "largecsv"
    [source_files] => "test?output=csv"
    [csv_delimiter] => ","
)
```

To get rid of the quotes then parse it as `ini` settings:

```
$result = parse_ini_string(implode("\n", $result[0]));
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [include_rows] => 1-10
    [debug_mode] => no
    [source_type] => guess
    [path] => largecsv
    [source_files] => test?output=csv
    [csv_delimiter] => ,
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer as well! A simple solution that does the job! I really do appreciate it! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can match the attribute names and their values using

```php
([^\s=]+)=(?|"([^"]*)"|(\S+))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Eh2eu2/1). *Details*:

- `([^\s=]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than whitespace and `=` chars
- `=` - an `=` sign
- `(?|"([^"]*)"|(\S+))` - Branch reset group:

  - `"([^"]*)"` - `"`, then any zero or more chars other than `"` captured into Group 1, and then a `"`
  - `|` - or
  - `(\S+)` - Group 2: any one or more non-whitespace chars

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/vOeou):

```php
$sc = '[csvtohtml_create include_rows="1-10" 
debug_mode="no" source_type="guess" path="largecsv" 
source_files="test?output=csv"  csv_delimiter="," ]';
if (preg_match_all('~([^\s=]+)=(?|"([^"]*)"|(\S+))~', $sc, $ms)) {
    print_r(array_combine($ms[1],$ms[2]));
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [include_rows] => 1-10
    [debug_mode] => no
    [source_type] => guess
    [path] => largecsv
    [source_files] => test?output=csv
    [csv_delimiter] => ,
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer and good explanation! I really do appreciate it! :-)